# Spring Web-Service :what are SAAJ and AXIOM

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

**SAAJ is based on DOM, the Document Object Model.**
What is meant by this statement?

**AXIOM is based on StAX, the Streaming API for XML.**
What is meant by this statement?

Which is better?

I want to clear the concept regarding to both APIs.
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DOM model reads the entire document into memory before extracting things from the nodes.
Stax parse the document without keeping it in memory.

So, need to reference backwards and forwards in the xml and the xml content is small, use DOM, otherwise consider Stax.

Answer (score 2):

Better is to AXIOM because of its StAX (won't use memory) usage.